# Kinetic shape not immediately deleting on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, kineticjs

I have a Kinetic node with a shape/image which inherits deletion functionality from a prototype function. Among other things, the function uses the KineticJS destroy() function.

When I delete the node on a browser, the deletion works fine. When I try to delete the node on the same browser on the iPad I'm using, the shape/image doesn't remove itself from the layer until I tap somewhere else on the canvas.

The code looks something like this:

```
Node.prototype.delete = function(){
    ...
    this.visual.destroy();
    layer.draw();
}
```

where this.visual is either a Kinetic circle or a Kinetic image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create any fiddle?

Comment: @lavrton further investigation indicates that my problems are related to the layers I'm using. Unfortunately the code is quite lengthy and wouldn't be worth condensing into a jsfiddle, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the destroy() function to be extremely slow.  At times with my code it would take the destroy function up to 10 seconds to actually destroy the nodes.  If you aren't concerned with literally deleting the node from the layer/stage maybe try this:

```
this.visual.setAttr('visible', 'false');
```

or

```
this.visual.setAttr('opacity', 0);
```

It's a bit hacky, but it will hopefully increase the performance on ipad.

Comment: thanks for your response! I do need to actually delete the nodes in this case, but I haven't had issues with the destroy() function taking as much time as you've indicated.

Comment: I good example is hosted here: http://kineticjs-2048.appspot.com/.  Here if you select select the 'start over' button after playing the game it will refresh the browser.  I did this because I tried to call stage.destroy() or something along those lines, or tileLayer.destory.  Anyways, the call took forever!  Feel free to fork it and try to replace the browser refresh with a destroy.  You will be surprised at the result.  It is important to note that in order for it to take a while to destroy you need to play the game a bit.

Comment: also, take a look at the .clear() function for layers?  Maybe you could put that node in it's own layer and just clear the canvas.  I don't know how your logic works for this so that may not be relevant but it's worth a shot

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: It turned out that there was a problematic line of code a few lines prior to the layer redraw call, so removing that line fixed it!